# Buck Regulator IC Markings Identification

Tags: buck

I am looking at some type of Buck Regulator chip; 12VDC in-5.0VDC out; 
20-Lead, 3mm x 4mm GFN (6-leads, 4-leads, 6-leads, 4-leads; the text on it is:
line 1: < 418
line 2: LGCC
line 3: B824
Is there anyone that can help identifying this IC?
Thanks in advance,
anotheree

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words ...

Comment: Add a photo else you may earn downvotes. Also, you will need to earn reputation to get past the new user restrictions, so fill in your profile and participate!

Answer (score 1):

Seems that a Linear Technology LTC3626 would be a likely suspect.
Comes in a 20-pin 3x4mm QFN package with park marking LGCC.
http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3626f.pdf